# nanoseconds from clock_gettime() on mips router

Tags: c, posix, mips, timing, time.h

I am trying to get nanosecond resolution from `CLOCK_REALTIME` on a 1GHz MIPS router. When I compile the below code for x86 and run on a 1GHz vm, I get nanosecond resolution. When I compile for mips and run on a 1GHz router, it appears to round up to the microsecond.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **arge) {
  struct timespec tps, tpe;
  if ((clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tps) != 0)
      || (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tpe) != 0)) {
    perror("clock_gettime");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("%lu s, %lu ns\n", tpe.tv_sec-tps.tv_sec,
     tpe.tv_nsec-tps.tv_nsec);
  return 0;
}
```

Here are sample times:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ gcc clock.c -o clock_x86 -static -lrt
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ./clock_x86
0 s, 221 ns


vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc clock.c -lrt -static -o clock_mips
<...scp...>
root@OpenWrt:~# ./clock_mips
0 s, 3000 ns
```

Is there something I am misunderstanding about clocks, MIPS, processors, etc? I would expect a call to `CLOCK_REALTIME` to produce nanosecond granularity/resolution, regardless of processor architecture.

Further, if anyone could shed light on how these POSIX timers are implemented and how they are getting their measurements, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guaranteed granularity of the clocks is specified as at least 20ms in [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08_05).  Here's the snippet that is germane:

> The maximum allowable resolution for CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC clocks and all time services based on these clocks is represented by {_POSIX_CLOCKRES_MIN} and shall be defined as 20 ms (1/50 of a second). Implementations may support smaller values of resolution for these clocks to provide finer granularity time bases. The actual resolution supported by an implementation for a specific clock is obtained using the [clock_getres()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) function. If the actual resolution supported for a time service based on one of these clocks differs from the resolution supported for that clock, the implementation shall document this difference.

Basically, you need to call [clock_getres()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) to determine what the implementation-specified resolution actually is.  Don't do anything that assumes that it is more granular than 20ms.

Comment: That helps. When you mention "implementation-specified", are you referring to the kernel? That is, if I need better resolution, do I focus on finding a kernel that implements these timers differently?

Answer (score 2):

The *minimum* resolution supported by `clock_gettime` is nanoseconds.  But there is no guarantee that the system clock's resolution (or indeed the implementation of that function) will be higher or lower than that.

Call [`clock_getres`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) to query the resolution of the clock.